# React Unit Testing Jest History Push

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, history

I got this Method that I need to Test. I tried to mock the History but I couldn't get it working. I just want to check if there is a Button and if I click on it there should handle the DrawerToggle and push back to Path.

```
imports...

export const SettingsSidebar = ({ listItems }) => {
  const gobackPath = (history.location.state as any)?.gobackPath;

some methods...

  return (
...some other Codes

          <DrawerMenu>
            <GoBackButtonLg onClick={() => history.push(gobackPath)}>Zurück zum Workspace</GoBackButtonLg>
            <SidebarList>
              <SidebarListItem
                goBackButton
                button
                key={'goback'}
                icon={<GoBackButtonSm icon={faChevronLeft} />}
                onClick={() => handleMenuClick(gobackPath)}
              >
                Zurück zum Workspace
              </SidebarListItem>
              {listItems.map(res => (
                <SidebarListItem
                  button
                  key={res.name}
                  icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={res.icon} />}
                  onClick={() => handleMenuClick(res.path)}
                >
                  {res.name}
                </SidebarListItem>
              ))}
            </SidebarList>
          </DrawerMenu>
and so on...
  );
};

export default SettingsSidebar;
```

**The Test:**

```
imports...

const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useHistory: () => ({ push: mockHistoryPush }),
}));

describe('SettingsSidebar', () => {
    const mockHandleDrawerToggle = jest.fn();
    beforeAll(() => {
      configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
    });
 
    it('should have a button', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<SettingsSidebar listItems/>);
      const button = wrapper.find(GoBackButton);
      button.props().onClick();
      expect(mockHandleDrawerToggle).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
```

**The Failed Message**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `goBack` method from the `history` object returned from `useHistory`. Look below for an example of how this works, also instead of invoking `{selector}.props().click()` you have to simulate the click event with `enzyme`.

#### Example.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const ExampleComponent = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                data-testid="btn-go-back"
                onClick={() => history.goBack()}
            ></button>
            <button
                data-testid="btn-go-to-some-path"
                onClick={() => history.push("/to-some-path")}
            ></button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

#### Example.spec.jsx | Example.test.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ReactRouterDOM from 'react-router-dom';
import ExampleComponent from './Example';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
const mockHistoryGoBack = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useHistory: () => ({
        push: mockHistoryPush,
        goBack: mockHistoryGoBack,
    }),
}));

describe('Example', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('invokes the history go back function when the go back button is clicked by the user', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<ExampleComponent />);
        const btn = wrapper.find("[data-testid='btn-go-back']");
        btn.simulate('click');
        expect(mockHistoryGoBack).toBeCalled();
    });

    it('invokes the history push function when the go back button is clicked by the user', async () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<ExampleComponent />);
        const btn = await wrapper.find('[data-testid="btn-go-to-some-path"]')
        btn.simulate('click');
        expect(mockHistoryPush).toBeCalledWith('/to-some-path');
    });
});
```